# Show $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\psi(x)}=-1$

Tags: limits, special-functions

How to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\psi(x)}=-1
$$
where $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function.

Comment: Note that $\Gamma(x) = \frac{1}{x} + h(x)$ for some function $h(x)$ holomorphic near the origin. Then $$\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\psi(x)}=\frac{\Gamma(x)^2}{\Gamma'(x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{2}{x}h(x)+h(x)^2}{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+h'(x)}.$$ The rest is now clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use recurrence relations:
$$
  \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\psi(x)} = \frac{x \cdot \Gamma(x)}{x \cdot \psi(x)} = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{x \cdot \psi(x+1) - 1}
$$
Since $\Gamma(1) = 1$ and $\psi(1)$ is finite, the limit readily follows.